# Pygame curtain animation not working

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I'm new to StackOverflow and in my daily life I help friends do some programming.

So I have a question for you, I have a curtain background divided by two pictures and I want when I press the Down key to open a little bite the curtain. So here is my code, I don't know why it's not working, it drives me nuts :/ .

```
  
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
```

```
pygame.init()


fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 420))


fond1 = pygame.image.load("cpart1.jpg").convert_alpha()
fond2 = pygame.image.load("cpart2.jpg").convert_alpha()

fenetre.blit(fond1, (350,0))
fenetre.blit(fond2,(0,0))

pos_fond1 = 350
pos_fond2 = 0


pygame.display.flip()


continuer = 1
while continuer:
        for event in pygame.event.get():                   
            if event.type == QUIT:                      
                continuer = 0      
            if event.type == KEYDOWN :
                    if event.type == K_DOWN:
                            pos_fond1 = pos_fond1 - 20
                            pos_fond2 = pos_fond2 + 20


    fenetre.blit(fond1, (pos_fond1,0))
    fenetre.blit(fond2, (pos_fond2,0))

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
```

So I don't know I move the object within the x position and I don't know what's not working. Can you help me people of StackOverflow.

Comment: `if event.type == K_DOWN` should be `if event.key == K_DOWN`. When you have this little code, try to rewrite the program in a different file (without copying) and you'll most likely resolve problems that are caused by mistyping. It'll help you find an answer faster than positing it here. Also, try use English exclusively in your code, or else it might be hard for other people to help you when the code gets a bit larger.

Comment: Thanks dude, next time I will read my code properly before  I ask questions.

Comment: Now you have an answer to your question posted here and can do for the first time the exercise of accepting an answer (you have to click the `V`) . To upvote it you will need some more reputation points (15 if I know it right), but your vote will be put in a queue for later. Bonjour and WELCOME to stackoverflow :) .

Comment: Bonjour et merci pour la réponse :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below moves both pictures on any KEYDOWN. Uncomment the print() commands to get some insight about the events going on (greetings to France from Germany :) where `window` is `Fenster` quite close to `fenetre` which means in Pygame `display`):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 420))

fond1 = pygame.image.load("cpart1.jpg").convert_alpha()
fond2 = pygame.image.load("cpart2.jpg").convert_alpha()

fenetre.blit(fond1, (350,0))
fenetre.blit(fond2,(0,0))

pos_fond1 = 350
pos_fond2 = 0

pygame.display.flip()

continuer = 1
while continuer:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # print(event)        
        if event.type == QUIT:                      
            continuer = 0      
        if event.type == KEYDOWN :
            # print("KEYDOWN")
            pos_fond1 = pos_fond1 - 20
            pos_fond2 = pos_fond2 + 20

    fenetre.blit(fond1, (pos_fond1,0))
    fenetre.blit(fond2, (pos_fond2,0))

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Danke che, Halo from France ;) !